# Wall-Mounted Board Help

Tags: hardware, audio, camera, power, video

I've decided I want to make a wall mounted DAKboard with some personal improvements, but I'm new to the RPi, Linux, and DIY in general so I want to make sure I'm not going to do something wrong.

Goal:
DAKboard that uses a USB webcam for RTC and also to use the board as a "mirror." Speakers for audio playback for music and RTC.

I am following a combination of these 2 guides:
[Instructables for RPi Media Panel](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Media-Panel-fka-Digita/)
[DAKboard DIY](http://dakboard.com/blog/diy-wall-display/)

Parts List:
Raspberry Pi Model B - What I have already
Monitor - DELL S S2340L Monitor
Webcam - Logitech C270
HDMI Extractor - J-Tech HDMI to HDMI+Analog Audio
Speaker - USB Powered Speaker bar

Putting it Together:
An extension cord will be used to power the monitor, speakers, RPi, and the HDMI Extractor. The last three will be connected to usb to wall adapters. HDMI output from the Pi to the Extractor, which outputs HDMI to the monitor and audio to the Speakers. The RPi will have a wifi dongle and the webcam connected to its 2 usb ports.

Questions I have:
Will it work?
Is there a better/more cost efficient way to do this?
Are there better/more cost efficient parts to replace what I have?
In the DAKboard DIY Guide, a picture shows that the monitor's buttons seem to be wired to the Pi. The guide never mentions this. Should I get a USB Hub to be able to connect the wifi dongle, webcam, and monitor buttons? Will I need to download any libraries to be able to use those buttons?
I'm planning on using Raspbian, but if there's a better OS for this, I'd love to know.

I think that's all I have, but I'm probably missing some things or don't know what to ask. Thank you for your patience.

Can't post more than 2 links. If you need specifics on the hardware, I can post them plaintext perhaps.

Edit: To clarify, the RTC would be for join an online chatroom essentially, not hosting an RTC Server or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You will need a Raspberry Pi 2 for WebRTC and likely whatever you
  mean by [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTC)
- USB webcam can be an issue because the network is sharing usb so you
  may want to use the official cam for higher resolutions.
- It would be more cost efficient to just buy an android tablet if you
  don't already have most of the kit.
- Buttons are likely GPIO.
- Yes, Raspbian is the recommended OS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  By RTC, I do mean a web-based chat.  Probably would use AppRTC by google.  What about the Pi B wouldn't work with this if its just a website?   When you say the usb webcam wouldn't work well because of the network adapter, is this just because of the increased power draw or a different factor?

Comment: only the pi2 has the 4 cores and cpu power to do the video muxing in user-space required for webrtc, you could do a non web video chat but it would not be as simple for non linux clients. The IO on the pi is limiting so if you are moving video in+out on the network you have to split that speed in 2 then split it in 3 if you want video coming from a usb cam, + usb cams may chew up more CPU than the optimized official cam... so if you have the parts just try it and if you want higher bandwidth video then you know what to do.